# pandas agg to concat strings in some columns while keeping max value in others

Tags: pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID1' : ['A' , 'A', 'B'],
                    'ID2' : ['C' , 'D', 'E'],
                   'bool' : [True, True, False]})

df_agg = df.groupby('ID1').agg(lambda x: ';'.join(set(x))).reset_index()
bool_col = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID1'])[['bool']].reset_index(drop=True)
final_df = pd.concat([df_agg, bool_col], axis=1)
```

I want to string concat `ID2` when `ID1` is duplicated, bot only want to keep the largest value (True) for col `bool`. I almost have it here, but there has to be a better way

Comment: Feel free to upvote your chosen answer in addition to selecting it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `agg` with `dict`

```
out = df.groupby('ID1',as_index=False).agg({'ID2': lambda x : ','.join(set(x)),'bool' : 'last'})
Out[322]: 
  ID1  ID2   bool
0   A  C,D   True
1   B    E  False
```

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for the `largest` value of `bool` column; so i'll go with this approach:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID1').agg({
   'ID2': lambda x: ','.join(set(x)),
   'bool': 'max'
}).reset_index()
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  ID1  ID2   bool
0   A  C,D   True
1   B    E  False
```